# How go view accuracy for both classes rather than each class accuracy being shown individually in bert sentiment analaysis

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model

im pretty new at using bert and honestly i feel a bit lost. Ive been trying out various online github/kaggle codes to see how it works on my dataset. anyway im at the point that i get the accuracy of bert as well as the f1 score however the accuracy is shown for each label sepeartely rather than a weighted average of both. Additionally the accuracy is shown as a fraction. how do i manage to get a weighted average of the two labels? I have attached my results

the code for identifying the f1 score and accuracy is as follows:

```
def f1_score_func(preds, labels):
    preds_flat = np.argmax(preds, axis=1).flatten()
    labels_flat = labels.flatten()
    return f1_score(labels_flat, preds_flat, average = 'weighted')

def accuracy_per_class(preds, labels):
    label_dict_inverse = {v: k for k, v in label_dict.items()}
    
    preds_flat = np.argmax(preds, axis=1).flatten()
    labels_flat = labels.flatten()
    
    for label in np.unique(labels_flat):
        y_preds = preds_flat[labels_flat==label]
        y_true = labels_flat[labels_flat==label]
        print(f'Class: {label_dict_inverse[label]}')
        print(f'Accuracy:{len(y_preds[y_preds==label])}/{len(y_true)}\n')
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
, predictions, true_val = evaluate(dataloader_val)  #why _ ? reason behind this is evaluate function return 3 values and i don't require the 1st value i.e., loss_val_avg
accuracy_per_class(predictions, true_val)
```

the results are shown like this:

```
   100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00,  7.39it/s]
    Class: 0
    Accuracy:59/81
    
    Class: 1
    Accuracy:54/69
    
    
    F1: 0.7537174638487207
```

However i want my accuracy to be shown like this:0.65272 rather than fraction of the seperate classes

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html

Comment: Are you using keras? If so can you post the code to where you fit your model?

Answer (score 0):

You could take this loop:

```
for label in np.unique(labels_flat):
    y_preds = preds_flat[labels_flat==label]
    y_true = labels_flat[labels_flat==label]
    print(f'Class: {label_dict_inverse[label]}')
    print(f'Accuracy:{len(y_preds[y_preds==label])}/{len(y_true)}\n')
```

And expand it into this:

```
total_correct = 0
total = 0

for label in np.unique(labels_flat):
    y_preds = preds_flat[labels_flat==label]
    y_true = labels_flat[labels_flat==label]
    a = len(y_preds[y_preds==label])
    b = len(y_true)
    total_correct += a
    total += b
    print(f'Class: {label_dict_inverse[label]}')
    print(f'Accuracy:{a}/{b}\n')

print(f`Overall accuracy: {total_correct/total:.2f}\n')
```

(This is just a bit of hacking, based on knowing you have the class accuracies. There is bound to be a more efficient way of doing it if you are sure you never care about them, but as this code will never be a bottleneck, especially given that the context is a BERT model, worrying about it would be premature optimization.)